# Blazeface Openvino

Tags: tensorflow, model, computer-vision, regression, openvino

Hi I'm trying to create landmarks from the blazeface model with openvino. The model is running and I have in regression output a shape array of (1,896,16) with these values corresponding to tensors:

---

### [10.116998   2.7768276 29.180841  29.190268  -7.6588407 -1.8769206
7.955852   2.8945901 -1.1223608 11.560151   4.533435  13.420406
-7.406376  -9.7577505 25.858068  -1.905251 ]

### [10.240653   2.762262  29.685017  29.694557  -7.6490545 -2.103835
8.018975   2.6713266 -1.0454882 11.4031725  4.6832647 13.421963
-7.434411  -9.877215  26.122345  -2.0081995]

### [10.195236   2.7623253 29.391754  29.400812  -7.406289  -2.2815979
7.871913   2.3147857 -1.0604903 10.664557   4.600431  12.801059
-7.033283  -9.625556  25.726923  -1.9212234]

### [ 9.646918   2.7344685 28.515514  28.524525  -7.4333186 -1.8820286
7.6982303  2.9067798 -1.1013308 11.309927   4.33471   13.137727
-7.308227  -9.689351  24.914877  -1.7770973]

The problem is I don't know what kind of value the blazeface model output give me and how to create landmarks from that. I saw they use get_tensor function after regression results in tensorflow but I didn't find the equivalent with openvino:

https://gist.github.com/ogl4jo3/5ba673b61ecc82780299edbcdcca301a

If someone has an idea please.

Comment: Do you use Python or C++ to run the model?

Answer (score 0):

I had a brief look at the sample you provided and saw that `get_tensor` is used to get raw results from network. To get boxes you need to use `ProcessCPU` and `orig_nms`

I would suggest you to use Python API of Inference Engine from OpenVINO.
An example of usage is [the link](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/blob/master/inference-engine/ie_bridges/python/sample/object_detection_sample_ssd/object_detection_sample_ssd.py)

You can try to adapt the sample above for your use case and use the functions `ProcessCPU` and `orig_nms` to extract boxes from raw data.

Comment: But where did you find this kind of function ProcessCPU and  orig_nms I don't know them.

Comment: ProcessCPU: https://gist.github.com/ogl4jo3/5ba673b61ecc82780299edbcdcca301a#file-blaze_face_detect-py-L235

Comment: orig_nms: https://gist.github.com/ogl4jo3/5ba673b61ecc82780299edbcdcca301a#file-blaze_face_detect-py-L279